# Apply a function to every element in a list to every element in another list

Tags: haskell

I'd like a more elegant way to write the following two functions, ideally in one :

```
applyOperatorBetweenVariableLists:: [Variable] -> String -> [Variable] -> [Variable]
applyOperatorBetweenVariableLists firstList operator secondList = concat $ map (test firstList operator) secondList

test:: [Variable] -> String -> Variable -> [Variable]
test firstVariables operator secondVariable = concat $ map (applyOperatorBetweenVariables secondVariable operator) firstVariables
```

The declaration of `applyOperatorBetweenVariables` is :

`applyOperatorBetweenVariables:: Variable -> String -> Variable -> [Variable]`

I'm quite sure there must be a Prelude Function that does exactly this, or a very elegant way to write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done concisely with a `do` block:

```
applyOperatorBetweenVariableLists firstList operator secondList = do
  secondVariable <- secondList
  firstVariable <- firstList
  applyOperatorBetweenVariables secondVariable operator firstVariable
```

If you wanted to be even more concise, you could reorder the arguments to both `applyOperatorBetweenVariableLists` and `applyOperatorBetweenVariables`, and then use either [`liftJoin2`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/utility-ht-0.0.14/docs/Control-Monad-HT.html#v:liftJoin2) or [`bind2`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/util-0.1.14.0/docs/Util.html#v:bind2) to implement it (like my final sentence below but with it in place of `liftA2`).

---

My original answer was wrong, as it left a layer of nesting (i.e., should have done an extra `concat` or `join`):

<del>That's *almost* just `liftA2`, but your arguments are in a weird order. Here's how you'd implement what you wrote in terms of that:</del>

```
import Control.Applicative (liftA2)
applyOperatorBetweenVariableLists firstList operator secondList = liftA2 (flip applyOperatorBetweenVariables operator) secondList firstList
```

<del>From that definition, it should be clear how you could change and simplify that to `applyOperatorBetweenVariableLists = liftA2 . applyOperatorBetweenVariables` just by reordering the arguments to it and to `applyOperatorBetweenVariables`.</del>

Comment: Thanks. I had noticed it missed a concat.

Comment: There is an `Applicative` solution, namely `flip applyOperator  operator <$> secondList <*> firstList`. If you use `ApplicativeDo`, that might be what the `do` block desugars to.

Comment: @chepner Doesn't that have the same problem as my original wrong answer, in that it will create an extra layer of nesting?

Comment: Maybe I'm misinterpreting what the output should be (especially since my suggestion is the same as `liftA2`, just spelled differently).

Comment: But isn't your `do` block *also* the same, especially if `ApplicativeDo` is in use? The extra layer of nesting would come, I think, from using `test`, which your updated solution ignores.

Comment: @chepner Consider `do x <- xs; y <- ys; f xs ys` vs. `do x <- xs; y <- ys; pure (f xs ys)`. My original answer and your comment are basically the second, but based on the original code in the question, the OP wants the first.